# Process form on Same Page the perform JQuery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, form-submit

I'm trying build a script where the users click submit and a message displays using JQuery depending on the status of the form submission. I don't want to use the alert function but I'm open to doing so if it came down to is. So my question is how can I make it so that PHP processes the form on the same page and performs the JQuery animation I want it perform based on the success or failure of the submission.

Here is the HTML

```
<form id="validationformContact">
            <div class="col">
                <label id="name-label">Name</label>
                <input name="Name" placeholder="Enter Name" id="name-input">
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <label id="email-label">Email&nbsp;</label>
                <input name="Email" placeholder="Enter Email" id="emailInput">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <label id="phone-label">Phone</label>

                <div class="phone-wrapper">
                    <input name="PhoneOne" placeholder="###" class="phone" id="phone">
                    <input name="PhoneTwo" placeholder="###" class="phone"> 
                    <input name="PhoneThree" placeholder="####" class="phone"> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <label id="email-label">Concern&nbsp;</label>
                <select name="Concern" placeholder="Type here..." id="concern"> 
                    <option>Select Concern....</option>
                    <option>Safety</option>
                    <option>Travel</option>
                    <option>Something else...</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col" id="messageCon">
                <label id="message-label">Message&nbsp;</label>

                <textarea name="textaream" placeholder="Type message here..." id="message"></textarea>
            </div>
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="SubmitButton">
        </form>
```

Here is the code
PHP

```
<?php
            $to = "jamell405@gmail.com"; //There email address
            $from = $_POST['Email']; //User's email address
            $fname = $_POST['Name'];
            $phone_one = $_POST['PhoneOne'];
            $phone_two = $_POST['PhoneTwo'];
            $phone_three = $_POST['PhoneThree'];
            $concern = $_POST['Concern'];
            $message = $_POST['Message'];
            $subject = $fname . " " . "sent you a message!";
            $subject2 = "Confirmation of your message!";
            $message1 = $fname . " " . "has sent you a message, its contents are below" . "\n" . $message;
            $message2 = $fname . " " . "this a confirmation for your message you sent!";
            $header = "From:" . $from;
            $header2 = "From:" . $to;

            mail($to,$subject,$message1,$message);
            mail($from,$subject2,$message2);

            if(@mail($to,$subject,$message1,$message)) {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$('.confirmationContact').slidedown(500);</script>";
            }
            else {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Message failed to send!');</script>";
            } 
        ?>
```

Comment: Don't you want the page to reload after execute the PHP script?

Comment: without a method your form defaults to GET

Comment: @JoseRojas No, I want it all to happen on the same page.

Comment: Btw, your `mail()` headers are incorrect. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: @Mihai yeah I added the post method to the form. Its a no go :( I'm new to PHP

Comment: have you tried to add $(document).ready()

Comment: @JoseRojas Would I put this in the PHP if statement? I'll give it a shot

Comment: Yes, in your if statement

Answer (score 1):

Try return a json message to jQuery, like this:

```
$arrayResult = array();
if(@mail($to,$subject,$message1,$message)) {
   $arrayResult['sent'] = true;
   $arrayResult['message'] = 'Message sent successfully!';
   echo json_encode($arrayResult);
}
else {
    $arrayResult['sent'] = false;
   $arrayResult['message'] = 'Some error ocurred, please try again.';
   echo json_encode($arrayResult);
}
?>
```

then parse it and do the animation in jQuery, like this:

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $.post('myfile.php', {
            your:data,
            goes:here
        }, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

            result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            if (result.sent == true) {
                // your animation goes here
                alert(result.message)
            }else{
                // your animation goes here
                alert(result.message)
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```